# php code to display list of folders and a delete-button near each of them

Tags: php

I'm a beginner with php and need to write a code that displays a list of folders and a delete-button near each of them, in order to be able to cancel them.
Here's my code: ($array_dir is an array containing the names of the directories in the current folder)

```
$conto=count($array_dir);
echo"<table>";

for ($b=0;$b<$conto;$b++) {
    echo"<tr><td><a href=$array_dir[$b]>".$array_dir[$b].
    "</a><br>";
    echo"<form name='delete_dir_".$b."' action=
    '".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."' method='GET'>";
    echo"<input type='submit' name='butdelete".$b."' value='Delete'>";
    echo"</form></td><td>";
    $dir=$array_dir[$b];
    if ((isset($_GET['butdelete".$b."'])) && ($_GET['butdelete".$b."']==$dir)) {
        if(rmdir($dir)) {
            echo"The directory ".$dir." has been removed";
        }
        else  {
            echo"Could not remove directory ".$dir;
        }
    }
}
```

This output looks fine but when I click on the delete-button it doesn't delete the folder and doesn't even return any error. I can't really understand where the error is !

Comment: Can you put an example of the data in your `$array_dir`

Comment: for John Gerdsen: the vector array_dir is an string array containing the names of all directories present in the current work directory.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the colour coding, and you'll see you have a problem with your `$_GET` access.

In fact, the way your code is now, you are literally looking for a URL like:

```
http://example.com/mypage.php?butdelete%22.%24b.%22=delete-me
```

Try this instead:

```
$_GET['butdelete'.$b]
```

Side-note: Never use `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` in an `action`. Instead, just use `action=""` to refer to the current page.

Comment: Thank you Kolink! It's working now, in the sense that it deletes the folder. It only doesn't print the echoes: "could not remove directory" or "the directory has been removed".

Comment: It looks like you are missing spaces between your echo and your string.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntaxing is off causing you problems. I've fixed and also moved the file operations to the top of the script so that you list is up-to-date when performing deletes.

```
<?php 

//If form has been posted try and delete if dir exists in array
if((isset($_GET['butdelete'.$b])) && (array_search($_GET['butdelete'.$b], $array_dir)))
{
    $dir = array_dir[array_search($_GET['butdelete'.$b], $array_dir)];
    if(rmdir($dir))
    {
        echo "The directory ".$dir." has been removed";
        //Remove Dir from Array if deleted.
        unset($array_dir[array_search($_GET['butdelete'.$b], $array_dir)]);
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Could not remove directory ".$dir;
    }
}

$conto=count($array_dir);

//Output remaining directories

echo"<table>";
for($b=0;$b<$conto;$b++){
   echo"<tr><td><a href=$array_dir[$b]>".$array_dir[$b]."</a><br>";
   echo"<form name='delete_dir_".$b."' action='' method='GET'>";
   echo"<input type='submit' name='butdelete".$b."' value='Delete'>";
   echo"</form></td><td>";
}
echo "</table>";
?>
```

Comment: I'm sorry if this discussion is getting a bit long, but it still doesn't work, and doesn't cancel the folders.

Comment: Make sure you have permissions to remove those folders.

Comment: Yes I've checked and have them, however it returns an error that makes no sense on the line if(rmdir($dir)): Expecting ; or ,. Is it possible that Php5 doesn't support the previous command you gave, that is array_search?

Comment: I'm on mobile but have edited my solution. Try that out. I had a couple of errors. Sorry.